# Insert/Update/Delete an entity in a table using repository method or Entity Manager has trigger return the modified value

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-data-jpa, triggers

I am having a problem regarding the SQL trigger. I'm using Spring Boot, Spring Data Jpa and SQL Server. The code below is probably a prototype of the code base I'm working with because I don't even have the authority to view the trigger.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE french.dbo.jhi_user (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK__jhi_user__3213E83F70EE20E8 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Trigger (just pretend I have deleted in here also)

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_jhi_user
ON jhi_user
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'inserted' AS action, inserted.*
        FROM inserted
    END;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM updated)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'updated' AS action, updated.*
        FROM updated
    END;
END;
```

1. Whenever I use a method from Repository (**save**, **delete**) but using **get() is fine** => an error showed up: **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A result set was generated for update**
2. The same thing happens when I tried to use persist() from EntityManager the same error happened

2.1. if I use the Entity Manager to get the current transaction without @Transactional (Because I suspect it might be a transaction problem)

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(userMapper.toEntity(userDTO));
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
```

then I have this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead

3. If I use any Native Query => it's fine but the thing is I don't want to fill 40+ attributes manually...
4. If I get the entity and edit it (managed entity after editing the changes will be persisted to the database) => Nothing happens. No error whatsoever but the entity remains unchanged

**QUESTION**: How can I use repository method or EntityManager persist() if my entity has a trigger like this without modifying/turn the trigger on off or using Native Query.

Comment: There is no pseudo table `updated`, so if you aren't getting an error from referencing a table called `updated` that means it's referencing a *literal* table, probably `dbo.updated`. I doubt that is desired behaviour.

Comment: On a different note, returning a result set from a `TRIGGER` is deprecated and should not be done. If you need to return a result set while performing a DML operation, use an `OUTPUT` clause on DML statement.

Comment: The code base itself is ancient. So the database, well you can guess.  Nothing I can really do about the database. 

And about the trigger, I just add the updated part. If you remove it and keep the inserted part only => you will still face the same problem

Comment: Because you're still returning a result set in the trigger; don't. Switch to an `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: I just made a prototype of the code base I'm talking about. I don't even have the authority to view the trigger man. That's why I'm asking for help. Blaming me won't help

Comment: I'm not "blaming" anyone; I'm telling you about a problem in your SQL and the solution to fix that problem.

Comment: Is spring jdbctemplate an option for you to use instead of JPA/entitymanager? That way you are permitted to manage the transaction.

Comment: Nobody's blaming you here, they're just pointing out that the database design is flawed and needs to be fixed. Triggers emitting results sets like this is non-standard behaviour and causes problems with applications and ORMs that aren't expecting them - which is why JPA is complaining about result sets getting returned from an `update` statement in the first place. You need to speak with the people responsible and convince them to fix their breakage. Otherwise you're going to have to write a bunch of custom code to avoid the issue, which invalidates the usefulness of JPA or any other ORM.